# gwt no CssResource'WithLookup' method

Tags: css, gwt

I've stumbled into a situation with gwt that does not seem to have a way around.

I've created a Composite widget with many dynamic clipped Image's so I can move the clipping like a tile-map. All went well until I start using a json as a TextResource describing the layout. The ui-binder does not work in my case.

I got ClientBundleWithLookup and ConstantsWithLookup working fine, but there is no lookup for the CSS classes. The lookup of the style() [as in the many examples] gives you this obfuscated chunk of the original css file - but there is no way to map these giberish names to what was originally in the css and in the json definitions.

I then thought of a way around is to send my css as a TextResource rather than the CssResource and process it manualy.  After spending the entire day doing this - there is no styles on the browser since the generated gwt javascript look for these giberish names once running in the browser.

I need a way to lookup css style names at runtime, the ideal would be to have a CssResourceWithLookup class as well. Also there's no reflection so I cant map the java methods to pass to the setStyleName()'s.

I also spotted somewhere on google a way to produce a debug map of these names - however I don't see how this will actualy help me since these names change after every compile. So I'm throughly stuck. I just dont understand how the gwt team failed this 'lookup' functionality on half of the resource bundles.

Any one with a way around this - please?

Answer (score 1):

`@external` may help you : it turns class names obfuscation off.

In MyStyles.css:

```
  @external .style1, .style2;

   .style1{
       color: green;
   }

   .style2{
       color: red;
   }
```

In your Java code:

```
myTile1.addStyleNames("style1");
myTile2.addStyleNames("style2");
```